# Spring bean initializing dependencies with new keyword?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have some legacy code where the class is a Spring bean defined and initialized through xml. It is a singleton with a field member which is a class dependency. There is a setter method for it, so I am assuming its supposed to be set via Spring, although I didn't find any xml defining it. There is also a get() method for the dependency, it has a null check and if its null it manually creates it outside of Spring like so

```
Class Test{
    Dependency d;

    setD(Dependency d){this.d=d;}

    getD(){
        if(this.d==null){
            this.d = new Dependency();
        }return this.d
     }
}
```

I am trying to understand why this Spring bean is initializing a dependency outside of Spring and what are the implications if any, is this just bad/old design? or Am I not understanding something with how Spring works.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's a bad design, probably author wanted to provide fall-back for the case when D was not injected in spring. Another idea is an attempt to make D a lazy dependency. You should explore what's inside D.

Generally you can use @Required to mark the members that always should be injected. Or just use simple and nice constructor injection. If you're concerned about lazy injection, that's how Spring works by default.

Comment: You need to be careful with this approach because if  Test is a singleton which is the default stereotype, the same instance will be reused every time is injected in something else. Singletones are not threadsafe. And if you open the ability to replace its dependency you could have an unwanted behaviour.